# How can I create a DC-DC voltage multiplier

Tags: voltage, usb, dc, multiplier

I want to take the 5V output from a USB port and make it 12V, so that I can run a cooling fan which is 12V. Is there any circuit I can make at home myself? If the output voltage is not exactly 12V, it can be at least 11V so the fan can run smoothly.

Comment: I think JYelton's comment is correct. In the meantime, look up boost converters. (Which are also detailed in that post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an MC34063 boost converter circuit to do this cheaply.

[image]

The parts values will be different, but the circuit will be the same. Calculate the parts values using the equations in the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) page 11. If the port can supply 500mA without complaint, then you could get about 100mA @ 12V into the fan assuming 50% efficiency. USB only guarantees 100mA without negotiation.

Comment: The quickest way I know is this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/dHhAI.gif